# Is it correct to say, "He has never been so late."?

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage

If my friend doesn't arrive on usual time,then is the following phrase correct to say?

> "*He has never been so late."*

My concern was whether this phrase is usually spoken or not. First I thought I can say that, "He has never got this much late." But that is incorrect, I saw that from other source. So I wanted to know whether this phrase is correct or not? And do people usually use that?

Comment: Welcome! Please edit your question to tell us more about what concerns you about the phrase, so we can address that.

Comment: @Andy Bonner My concern was whether this phrase is usually spoken or not. First I thought I can say that, "He has never got this much late." But that is incorrect, I saw that from other source. So I wanted to know whether this phrase is correct or not? And do people usually use that?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, but please use the "Edit" link under the question to add clarification to the question itself. The [guidelines for topics covered here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) require that questions can't just ask "is this right," but must say *what* they think might be right or wrong about it (you get better answers that way). In this case, I'll go ahead and take the liberty of adding your comment into the question for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, "He has never been so late" is a good choice.

The problems with "*He has never got this much late*" are:

1. We don't usually use "get" with "late" for this meaning ([definition 1 a (1) here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/late)—meaning the same as "tardy"). We use some form of the verb *to be*: "He is late," "I am late."
2. We don't use "this much" to measure adjectives (e.g., we don't say "I'm this much tall.") We can use "*so* late," as you suggest, or just "*this* late," as Jack suggests. "This much" is more useful when measuring verbs: "I've never eaten this much."

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's correct. In the U.S., at least, you'd more likely hear *He's never been this late [before].*

Comment: Thanks for the additional suggestion.